# Creating a panda's dataframe out of a single variable that contains a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I am trying to get  dataFrame from this function :

```
def total_sum(self):
    c = defaultdict(int)
    for slot in self.data:
        c[slot['accountLabelType']] += slot['totalPrice']
    return(c)
```

it returns a variable that contains a whole dict with a key:value structure.

When I try to create the panda's dataframe like this :

```
def source_revenue(self):
        # df = pandas.DataFrame(self.data, columns=[
                            #   'Source Of Business', 'Revenue'])
        df = pandas.DataFrame({'CASH' : self.data})
        print(df)
```

I get this :

```
                                  CASH
BYD - Other                      500.0
BYD - Retail                    1584.0
```

But i want it to be like :

```
SOURCE                            CASH
BYD - Other                      500.0
BYD - Retail                    1584.0
```

But I can't do `df = pandas.DataFrame({'SOURCE : self.data[0]'CASH' : self.data[1})`

Because it is a dictionary, how do I properly extract both values so I can create the dataframe ?

sample output dictionary :

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Spa': 3052, 'GS - Retail': 386, 'SCH Beverage - A La Carte': 119, 'BYD - Retail': 1584, 'BYD - Transport': 42498, 'BYD - Other': 500, 'BYD Food - Catering Banquet': 53796, 'Orchard Retail': 130, 'SCH - Retail': 375.4, 'SCH - Transport': 888, 'BYD Food - A La Carte 瓦厂食品－零点': 68365, 'XLM Beverage - A La Carte': 38, 'GS Food - A La Carte': 48, 'BYD Rooms 瓦厂房间': 5148, 'BYD Beverage - A La Carte': 39401.5, 'SCH - Food - A La Carte': 96})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the dictionary to two arrays, one for keys and other for values:

```
data = {
    'test1': 10,
    'test2': 20,
    'testx': 40,
    'foo': 50,
}

items = data.items()
pd.DataFrame({'keys': [i[0] for i in items], 'values': [i[1] for i in items]})
```

Assigning variable `items` is important because order may not be deterministic.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you !

Comment: This might be simpler:
`df =  pd.DataFrame({'keys': data.keys(), 'values': data.values()})`

Answer (score 4):

You could just put your dictionary into a list:

```
import pandas as pd
some_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 11, 'd': 66}  
df = pd.DataFrame([some_dict])
```

Comment: This works and is by far the simplest answer. This answer should be much higher.

Answer (score 2):

Ok first, the values should be lists:
let's say your dictionary is `dico`, first convert values to lists:

```
dico = { x:[y] for x,y in dico.iteritems() }
```

Then build your dataframe:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(dico)
```

Comment: ```ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index```

Comment: can you print a sample of your dictionary?